# Connection timed out when trying to access Pastebin with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, http, pastebin

A series of failed attempts led me to try a simple GET request to the [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) website's main page with Qt 5.1 :

```
typedef void (QNetworkReply::*ReplyError)(QNetworkReply::NetworkError);

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://www.pastebin.com"));
    QNetworkReply * reply = manager.get(request);

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply] {
        qDebug() << reply->readAll();
    });

    QObject::connect(reply, static_cast<ReplyError>(&QNetworkReply::error), 
                    [reply](QNetworkReply::NetworkError code) {
        qDebug() << "Error code   : " << code;
        qDebug() << "Reply        : " << reply->readAll();
        qDebug() << "Error string : " << reply->errorString();
        qDebug() << "HTTP status  : " << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    });

    return app.exec();
}
```

After a while, the console outputs :

```
Error code   : 99
Reply        : ""
Error string : "Connection timed out"
HTTP status  : 0
```

I also found out that it gets me ip-banned from their website for ~10 minutes (I can't access the website using my browser unless I change my VPN location).

I tried the same request in python and it worked fine.

What is the problem here ? Is the issue coming from Qt or Pastebin?

#### Edit :

Tried with Qt 4.8.5. Got the same result.

#### Edit 2 :

I tried almost 2 months later with the same version of the framework and it works now. I guess they fixed something on the Pastbin website...

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-download-main-cpp.html) example for simple download operation on any url including pastebin.

It is basic implementation for a download manager but you should be able to strip it down for your needs. If this implementation also fails with same timeout then it may be something wrong with pastebin url or pastebin accessibility over network.

Moreover in your code, connection of finished and error signal should be done before `manager.get(request)`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Just tried the example. Still gets a timeout for Pastebin sadly. Works fine with other websites.